# Верны ли знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

*«Решила узнать у симферопольцев на что в первую очередь, по их мнению, стоит обратить внимание новому главе города».*

Comment: Не стоит тему вопроса переносить (дублировать) в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

**Решила узнать у симферопольцев, на что в первую очередь, по их мнению, стоит обратить внимание новому главе города.**

Запятая ставится в придаточном в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, **НА ЧТО ― союзное слово**, опорное слово в главном предложении — глагол узнать (что?).

Comment: решила узнать у симферопольцев что? вопрос .....

Comment: на что стоит обратить внимание - ответ

Comment: Да,  здесь всё верно.